# Rearrange values in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

We are getting data in the following format in a table:

[image]

As we can see in the above screenshot:

Item1 was mapped to only 1 value = Data1. (Column A and B)

Item2 was mapped to Data11 and Data12. (Column A and B)

Item2 Data11 and Data12 were also mapped to Item1.Data1 (Column A-B & C-D)

For this entire mapping, we are getting the value in

We want to Pivot the data and display it in the following format using VBA (We have 9 columns Item1 to Item9. For simplicity, we have added only 3 columns below):

[image]

We did brainstorm but did not get any answer. Please help us in which is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm lost.  Why. isn't `Data2` in the result set?  I think you need more explanation.  The relationship between the result and data is not obvious.

Comment: + it would be better if you provide your test data as text, not screenshots...

Comment: Why is "Data1" repeated 5 times? Shouldn't it show up twice only? "Data11" should show up three times, and "Data12" 4 times. The question is confusing [to me].

Comment: It is like a parent-child relationship. Data1 has two childs Data11 and Data 12. Data 11 inturn has childs Data21 and Data 22. We want to show all the combinations from the root till the leaf element in this tree. Data1, Data11, etc are just for reference. please do not check for why Data2 is missing or not. Data1 can be "ABC-Corporation" and Data11 can be "XYZ-Corporation" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This query uses subquery factoring to get your answer:

```sql
WITH test_data (a, b, c, d) AS
(
  SELECT 'Item1', 'Data1', 'Item2', 'Data11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Item1', 'Data1', 'Item2', 'Data12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Item2', 'Data11', 'Item3', 'Data21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Item2', 'Data11', 'Item3', 'Data22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Item2', 'Data12', 'Item3', 'Data21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Item2', 'Data12', 'Item3', 'Data22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Item2', 'Data12', 'Item3', 'Data23' FROM DUAL
),
subquery_factoring (Item1, Item2, Item3, Query_Level) AS
(
  SELECT td.b, td.d, NULL, 0
  FROM test_data td
  WHERE td.a = 'Item1'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT sf.Item1, sf.Item2, td.d, sf.query_level+1
  FROM subquery_factoring sf
  INNER JOIN test_data td ON td.a = 'Item2' AND sf.item2 = td.b
  WHERE sf.query_level = 0
)CYCLE Item1 SET is_cycle TO 'Y' DEFAULT 'N'
SELECT sf.item1, sf.item2, sf.item3
FROM subquery_factoring sf
WHERE sf.query_level = 1
```

****Edit1: Much Simpler****

I might have overthought this a bit.  Instead, maybe try this:

```sql
WITH test_data (a, b, c, d) AS
(
  SELECT 'Item1', 'Data1', 'Item2', 'Data11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Item1', 'Data1', 'Item2', 'Data12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Item2', 'Data11', 'Item3', 'Data21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Item2', 'Data11', 'Item3', 'Data22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Item2', 'Data12', 'Item3', 'Data21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Item2', 'Data12', 'Item3', 'Data22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Item2', 'Data12', 'Item3', 'Data23' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT td1.b AS Item1, td1.d AS Item2, td2.d AS Item3
FROM test_data td1
INNER JOIN test_data td2 ON td1.c = td2.a;
```

That produces the same results.